# How to unit test JavaScript in a Qt application?

Tags: javascript, qt, unit-testing

I would like to add a bit of JavaScript unit testing to my Qt application, and tried my preferred JS test setup: Karma test runner and Jasmine. Problem: in my application, I am using `.pragma library` in several Javascript files, which then throws a syntax error or reports an unexpected token, respectively.

I totally agree that `.pragma library` is not valid JavaScript and understand that test runs fail because of that, but it is quite common, valid and useful in a Qt project - so how can I work around this? Or should I be using another test setup?

Comment: AFAICT, a work around for a feature that is not implemented is to grab the source code and implement the feature.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have heard of that workaround. But when I stumble over a basic problem like this, without seeing anyone else discussing it, I always consider that I am missing something obvious, even more as I am rather new to Qt.